# How to watch twig files with Webpack and Symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm playing around with webpack and Symfony 2.
For now I've managed them to work together.

And when I save a js or css file, my browser is automatically reloaded with webpack-dev-server.
But how I can tell webpack to reload the browser when I change and save a Twig file ?

Here are my project structure :

```
root
├── app
│   ├── config
│   └── Resources
│       └── assets
│           └── img
│           └── js
│               └── index.js (my entry point)
│           └── scss (my styles files)
│       └── views (All my twig files are here)
├── src
│   └── AppBundle
├── nodes_modules
├── web
    ├── bundles
    └── build (generated files by webpack)
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

And my webpack config :

```
...
module.exports = {
    entry: 'app/Resources/assets/js',
    output: {
        path: 'web/build',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/build/',
        pathinfo: true
    }
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css', {allChunks: true}),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['eslint', 'jscs'],
                include: PATHS.app
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel?cacheDirectory'},
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')},
            {test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|svg|woff2?|eot|ttf)$/i, loader: 'url', query: {limit: 10000}}
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', '']
    }
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'web/'),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: '8090'
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind,

I found a plugin that does what i want :
https://github.com/man27382210/watchFile-webpack-plugin.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Another solution could be this package, if you want to manage it a bit more through symfony and twig: https://github.com/hostnet/webpack-bundle